# Session & Token Fixation in IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1

Tags: security, ibm-mobilefirst

We're developing a hybrid app, cordova based using MFP 7.1 It was observed that the app uses client ID as session ID. As follow in the red box

[image: Client ID]
It was found that the Client ID will not be changed until reinstallation of the application. Whenever a user login on the device, its identity will be associated with the Client ID. With the Client ID, it may be able to retrieve another ID WL-Instance-ID from the application server. With valid Client ID and WL-Instance-ID, attacker will be able to access the application with the privilege of the victim user.

How to dissociate Client ID and Session ID? i.e. it should not be possible to retrieve a valid Session ID/token just by Client ID. And Session ID/token should be changed during change in security context.

We follow the instructions from here to implement the authentication
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/custom-authentication/

- Create mobileSecurityTest to protect adapter’s procedures; it's in SecurityTests section.

  `<mobileSecurityTest name="LoginAdapter-securityTest">
     <testUser realm="LoginAdapterRealm" />
     <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
     <testDirectUpdate mode="disabled"/>
  </mobileSecurityTest>`
- Use AdapterAuthenticator to handle userIdentity, and define two methods LoginAdapter.onAuthRequired, LoginAdapter.onLogout in LoginAdapter to handle security request.

  `<realm loginModule="LoginAdapterModule" name="LoginAdapterRealm">
     <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
     <parameter name="login-function" value="LoginAdapter.onAuthRequired" />
     <parameter name="logout-function" value="LoginAdapter.onLogout" />
  </realm>`
- Define module to create and store user identities that is used by LoginAdapterRealm; it's in loginModules section.

  `<loginModule name="LoginAdapterModule" expirationInSeconds="1800">
    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
  </loginModule>`

Comment: Could you specify what a user session is bound to? Is it bound to `X_WL_ClientId` or `X-WL-Session` or both?

Comment: @Juxhin I haven't verified `X-WL-Session` header yet. One thing I know is that Client ID does not represent user sessions, but it can be used to refer to the current active session. So if an attacker has the Client ID and there is a session available in the same device, he/she can access authenticated procedures.